# How to prevent ToString("0,0") to return 00

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a bunch of integers that I have to display in one of my views.

I display them this way:

```
int myVariable = 12500;
myVariable.ToString("0,0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(",", " ")
```

If myVariable contains 12500, it will display: 12 500. This is exactly what I want.

However, if myVariable contains 0, it will display: 00. Instead of 00, I want 0 to be displayed.

I've looked on MSDN about Custom number formats and I haven't found anything that could help me. If it's possible, I would like to not be able to do some more string management (replace, etc). Just switching the format from 0,0 to something that would work for me.

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/) could help

Comment: I edited my question to replace INT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
myVariable.ToString("#,0", ...)
```

Although I'd be surprised if one of the standard string formats didn't handle this. For example, you could use:

```
myVariable.ToString("N0", ...)
```

Also note that instead of using the invariant culture and then replacing comma with space, you could create your own culture (based on the invariant culture, potentially) with a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) of " ".

Sample code:

```
// You don't need to create this every time. Create it once and put it in a static variable.
var culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

Console.WriteLine(12345.ToString("N0", culture)); // 12 345
```

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster: Yup, that's just what I'd determined too.

Comment: Do you mean that I could use N0 without the replace?

Comment: @LePad: Yes, or the "#,0" version - so long as you use the right culture. See my edit for a sample.